# Make the carousel scroll up while using a GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My Current Widget tree is something like this :

```
return Container(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        myCarouselWidget(),
        GridView.count(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          children: myDummyProductList,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now what I want is that as I scroll the carousel should scroll up and the gridView should gradually cover the entire page.

What I tried :

1. physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
2. Removing the SingleChildScrollView and wrapping the GridView in an Expanded widget worked but the carousel won't scroll up.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after some tinkering and researching. In short, I used a CustomScrollView and put the carousel in the SliverAppBar which hides as I scroll up. This is my Widget tree as of now:

```
return Container(
  child: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        floating: false,
        pinned: true,
        elevation: 4,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        expandedHeight: carouselHeight,
        title: Text(
          "MyTitle",
        ),
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: myCarousel
        ),
      ),
      SliverPadding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
        sliver: SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          children: myDummyProductList,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main axis direction of a grid is the direction in which it scrolls.
The most commonly used grid layouts are `GridView.count`, which creates a layout with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis, and `GridView.extent`, which creates a layout with tiles that have a maximum cross-axis extent. A custom `SliverGridDelegate` can produce an arbitrary 2D arrangement of children, including arrangements that are unaligned or overlapping.

```
CustomScrollView(
  primary: false,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text("He'd have you all unravel at the"),
            color: Colors.green[100],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
            color: Colors.green[200],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
            color: Colors.green[300],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text('Who scream'),
            color: Colors.green[400],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text('Revolution is coming...'),
            color: Colors.green[500],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: const Text('Revolution, they...'),
            color: Colors.green[600],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image: this is the representation of the above code]

Comment: I understand the use of Silver child but as I mentioned I have to add the carousel part in the scroll too which is not a Silver. I am using this library for carousel 
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro
It is a RenderBox and not a RenderSilver.